# Is benzyl chloride or allyl chloride more reactive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, reactivity

What compound is more reactive, **benzyl chloride** [(chloromethyl)benzene] or **allyl chloride** (3-chloroprop-1-ene)? I know that both have a higher reactivity than alkyl and aryl chlorides.

[image]

Comment: Not really, I was exercising SN1 and SN2 mechanisms and I was just wondering. I am thinking that Allyl Chloride is more reactive because the Benzyl Chloride is stabilized by conjugation. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @user50487 Could you please edit your question to include those thoughts (and the rationale behind them)?